# How to remove id from select active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

Query on console

```
User.select('email','dob')
```

returns,

```
[#<User:0x000000084a9b08 id: nil, email: "xyz@zyx.com">,
```

Why am I getting id attributes in rails 4?  How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you desired output

```
User.pluck(:email, :dob)
```

Answer (score 39):

Pluck only returns the values if you want keys and values then
try this:

`User.select('email','dob').as_json(:except => :id)`

In my case the desired result was a JSON object. So, inside the *as_json* method
you can exclude any column you desire

(additionally you can invoke object methods or access associated tables as well)

Comment: Most flexible answer, works for aggregations as well

Comment: This answer solved for me. It would be awesome if there was an `unselect()` method for better readability, or if `select()` accepted arguments prepended with `-` to indicate they're not wanted. `as_json` feels more to do with the format (rather than the contents) of the data.